# How to format today's date in this format?

Tags: apex, datetime

How can we format today's date in the following date/time format?

2015-04-29T06:17:44.000-07:00

it represents yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:sss-UTC

any suggestions will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: in what? apex, VF, formula field?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [DateTime.format(String)](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_datetime.htm#apex_System_Datetime_format_2) method and a [Java SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) as the parameter.

```
System.debug(Datetime.now().format('yyyy-MM-dd\'T\'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ'));
```

gives:

> 2015-05-12T15:43:36.358-0700

This will be for the current users local time zone. Note:

> "If the time zone cannot be determined, GMT is used."

If you want more control over the timezone you can use the [DateTime.format(String, String)](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_datetime.htm#apex_System_Datetime_format_3) method and specify the TimeZone.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there's a typo here.

Comment: Ahem, whoops. Fixed now.

Comment: @DanielBallinger Thanks a lott. This solved my issue